# adding value to field inside frames

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    Dim hDocument As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim hElementCollection As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim hInputElement As MSHTML.htmlInputElement

    IE.Visible = True

    Dim url As String
    url = "www.blah.com"

    IE.Navigate url

    Call SleepIE(IE)
    PauseApp 3

    Dim xSom, xFrame As Object
```

'this is checking to see if original link led to log in page and if so log in, otherwise its redirected

```
If IE.LocationURL = url Then
Set xFrame = IE.Document.getElementById("infoView")
        PauseApp 3 ' pausing application for 3 seconds for everything to load
        Do While True
        xFrame.contentWindow.Document.getElementById("username").Value = "username"
         If Err.Number = 0 Then
                Exit Do
            ElseIf Err.Number > 0 And Err.Number <> 91 Then
                Exit Function
            End If
            Err.Clear
        Loop

        Do While True
        xFrame.contentWindow.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "password"
         If Err.Number = 0 Then
                Exit Do
            ElseIf Err.Number > 0 And Err.Number <> 91 Then
                Exit Function
            End If
            Err.Clear
        Loop
        xFrame.contentWindow.Document.Forms(0).submit
    End If

    PauseApp 3
    Call SleepIE(IE) ' awaiting ie ready state
```

'this is where im getting stuck
'im trying to assing value to "ListingURE_searchText", below doesnt work

```
        Set hElementCollection = IE.Document.frames("mainFrameSet").Document.frames("dataFrame").Document.frames("dataFrameSet").Document.frames("workspaceFrameSet").Document.all
        For Each hInputElement In hElementCollection
            If hInputElement.getAttribute("id") = "ListingURE_searchText" Then
            hInputElement.Value = "555"
            End If
        Next hInputElement
```

i also tried

```
    Set hElementCollection = hDocument.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
        For Each hInputElement In hElementCollection
            If hInputElement.getAttribute("id")
               hInputElement.Value = "test"
            End If
        Next hInputElement
```

blow is the short version of page source which is 20 pages long

```
<head>
<frameset id="mainFrameSet" rows="*">
<frame id="headerPlusFrame" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"     src="../listing
<iframe id="dataFrame"
<html>
<head>
<frameset id="dataFrameSet" rows="*,20">
<frameset id="centerFrameset" cols="*,0">
<frame id="workspaceFrame" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="2"    title="Workspace" src="workspace.do" name="workspaceFrame">
<html>
<head>
<frameset id="workspaceFrameSet" class="panelFrame" border="0" framespacing="0"     frameborder="0" rows="18,*">
<frame id="workspaceHeaderFrame" scrolling="no" noresize="" marginwidth="0"  marginheight="0" src="workspaceHeader.do?title=" title="Workspace Header" name="workspaceHeaderFrame">
<frame id="workspaceBodyFrame" noresize=""
<html>
<head>
<body onresize="resizeUreWithTimeout()" onload="onLoad()">
<form id="listingForm"
<table id="ListingURE" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="width: 1249px; height: 376px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<table id="ListingURE_toolbar0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
<td>
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="ListingURE_toolbar0Container"
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr valign="middle">
<td>
<input id="**ListingURE_searchText**" class="textinputs" type="text" value=""  name="ListingURE_searchText" onselectstart="ev
```

Comment: Your HTML is messed up pretty badly. I guess you'd best start with fixing that. Furthermore your question is totally unclear. What are you using to do what. What have you tried? Think about providing more of these details.

Comment: i cant paste 20 pages of HTML so i just pasted what i thought was important,i have no knowledge of HTML so if i should add more let me know. i tried using ie.document.getElementById and getElementsByTagName to set .value to that field but no luck im trying to do something down the lines of Document.getElementById("ListingURE_searchText").Value = "abc"

Answer (score 0):

What you are using looks more like oldskool VBscript. You really shouldn't use that.

Here is an example of how to use getElementById with JavaScript to set a textbox value:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="ListingURE_searchText" />
    <input type="button" onclick="fnSetValue()" title="Set value" />
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function fnSetValue() {
        document.getElementById('ListingURE_searchText').value = 'testing 123';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: my code above works on sites with no frames so i think my issue has something to do with frames. 
i tried below as well but no luck

    IE.Document.frames("mainFrameSet").Document.frames("dataFrame").Document.frames("dataFrameSet").Document.frames("workspaceFrameSet").Document.getElementByID("ListingURE_searchText").value = "testing"

Comment: Search a bit on "script communicate between frames". It can be done, but it's quite tricky. Why do you need the frames anyway?

Comment: i need to gather some information from our website so i have to go to page with all frames